# Corba Naming_Service creates so many UDP connections

Tags: c++, corba, ace, tao

The Corba Naming_Service creates so many UDP connections and they are still remained even when the clients are disconnected. It goes up to 60K connections.

AIX 5.3, TAO Version 1.5a_p22 and ACE Version 5.5a_p22

Below is the losf:

```
Naming_Se 692382 slist  319u  IPv4 0xf10006000f914200             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  320u  IPv4 0xf10006000d224800             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  321u  IPv4 0xf1000600109d6200             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  322u  IPv4 0xf10006000961b600             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  323u  IPv4 0xf1000600027fde00             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  324u  IPv4 0xf10006000acd8a00             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  325u  IPv4 0xf100060009aa8200             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  326u  IPv4 0xf100060009854800             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  327u  IPv4 0xf100060002bce400             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  328u  IPv4 0xf1000600094a3a00             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  329u  IPv4 0xf10006000b4bdc00             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  330u  IPv4 0xf10006000017aa00             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  331u  IPv4 0xf100060004453200             0t0    UDP *:*
Naming_Se 692382 slist  332u  IPv4 0xf100060009342200             0t0    UDP *:*
```

Where/How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should try asking on http://serverfault.com as well. They might have more experience on this stuff...

Comment: Thank you, @MihaiTodor. Very good suggestion. I will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that AceTao Naming_Service creates new UDP sockets when it is connected and leaves as dump even when client disconnects it. I think that is the bug in ACE5.5 TAO1.5. 
Upgrading to ACE5.6 TAO1.6 p13 solved the problem.